# Chrome css transform scale/font-size issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, font-size

CSS

```
.checkbox label:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.checkbox .cr {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
    border-radius: .25em;
    width: 4vw;
    height: 4vw;
}

.checkbox .cr .cr-icon {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    line-height: 0;
    top: 2vw;
    left: 1.2vw;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"] + .cr > .cr-icon {
    transform: scale(3) rotateZ(-20deg);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .cr > .cr-icon {
    transform: scale(2) rotateZ(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
        <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

External CSS

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

I have a custom css checkbox. Suppose when I narrow down the screen width, the size of checkbox and the tick sign will be decreased in scale.

It works fine in IE no matter how small of the screen size is and the tick could be very very small in scale which is expected. The problem is in Chrome, the tick sign will be overflow when the screen width is very small.

I've set up JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7fuL1zh3/5/
Hope someone could give me a hand THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

You have used "vw" as a unit for font sizes and positions etc. 
So "vw" means, it is relative to the width of the view port. So when resizing the browser/viewport, those values relatively applied.

You can use absolute length units rather having relative length units like.

Eg. `font-size: 1.5px`

Ref. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: px is not my option because my page is under responsive design so I have to use vw so that the size of all elements and font would be changed depends on the screen width. The main point is the JSFiddle is work under IE so I think there are something wrong or bug for Chrome. Thanks anyway

Comment: What is the version of your IE browser? And I'm using IE 11 and same behavior like chrome.

Comment: So please check the browser version support for "vw"

Comment: my IE version is 11.0.9600 18738.

I captured my screen here:
https://imgur.com/a/YbakO
You will see the tick is always in scale in IE while Chrome has problem.

I found a discussion said Chrome has problem to show font-size smaller than 12px. Chrome always treats font smaller than 12px as 12px so that the font can't get smaller when screen width decrease.

Comment: both my current IE and Chrome support vw. Initially, the tick font (both IE and Chrome) is in scale when screen width changed from like 1500px to 1000px. My question is when I narrow down the screen width to be very very very very small like 100px, the tick font in Chrome is like freezed at 12px and can't get smaller while IE can have a very very very small font to keep the tick font in scale

Comment: Oh. So your chrome can show the tick totally inside the checkbox? Could you tell me your chrome version?

Comment: Yes. No issues in chrome. Version 61.0.3163.91 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Upgraded Chrome to v.61 but still no luck.. Screen cap: https://imgur.com/a/VtGKz